# Don't reload Visualforce page to top of the page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a problem that it is driving me crazy. I have radio buttons on my Visualforce page, some of the radio buttons are hidden when you first open the page, but if let's say the radio button #10 is changed to the option 'Yes', I refresh the page and show 2 more radio buttons.

My problem is that it's always reloading the page to the top and I don't want it.
I have this radio buttons inside pageblock and outputpanel.
I was able to make it work to go to a button but not a radio button.

On Apex I have differents functions to each radio button that displays hidden radio buttons.
I called this function like this:

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!contact.LivesInAmerica__c}" label="Do you live in America?" id="rb1">
    <apex:selectoptions value="{!types}"></apex:selectoptions>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!functionFirst}"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
<apex:selectRadio rendered="{!showRB1}" value="{!contact.Street__c}" label="Street">
     <apex:selectoptions value="{!types}"></apex:selectoptions>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

And this code on Apex Class Controller:

```
public PageReference functionFirst(){
    if(contact.LivesInAmerica__c == 'Yes'){
        showRB1= true;
    }
    else {
        showRB1= false;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can write your function as: `public void functionFirst() { showRB1 = contact.LivesInAmerica__c == 'Tes'; }` No need for a return value or if statement here.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reRender target, and the page won't move:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!functionFirst}" reRender="theForm" />
```